# How should I convert 5 gallon buckets into pots?

Tags: containers

I don't have some pots/room in the garden to plant elephant garlic into, so I was planning to plant in 5 gallon pots. What do you suggest I do to make them into pots, but can use them in the winter?

Comment: There are some interesting plans on how to make 5 gallon buckets into self watering planters. This one looks pretty neat. http://extension.umd.edu/growit/food-gardening-101/self-watering-containers-converting-5-gallon-bucket-mini-garden

Answer (score 2):

You can drill some holes for drainage, and use potting mix so that it drains properly.

I planted some garlic into air pruning pots over the weekend to see how they'd go since my soil is very water logged at present.  We've just short a few days of the shortest day of the year, the traditional time to plant garlic.

I'm guessing you're not in the southern hemisphere, so what season are you planting yours?

[image: garlic in air pots]

Answer (score 2):

- Drill some holes (2-4) in the bottom for drainage.
- How are you going to make sure it gets enough light of the right type? Keep in mind most grow lights must be replaced every 6 months. They don't last forever with 12-16 hours of use every day.
- In the cooler months in your house how will you control mold? I use this solution to water: 1 part hydrogen peroxide and 10-12 parts water. It works great.

Comment: how many holes?
Others may need a grow light, but I have plenty of yard to spare, just not plenty of garden to plant elephant garlic.

Comment: 2-4 holes in the bottom of each bucket is fine. Water will find the holes and drain out.

Comment: Would you remove all your links about lighting.  The question is about pots for outdoor garlic.  Garlic needs to be wintered outside so that it forms bulbs correctly.  Thanks,